# Using ruby 'or equals' ||= on methods that return a hash or nil

Tags: ruby, hash, null

I have a method that returns a hash, or nil:

```
def person_of_age(age)
  some_hash = @array_of_hashes.select { |h| h.age == age }.last
  return some_hash
end
```

I want to use this hash like so:

```
my_height = 170
my_age = 30
if my_height < self.person_of_age(my_age)['height']
 puts "You are shorter than another person I know of the same age!"
end
```

Now, if the hash returns nil, ruby doesn't like me using ['height']:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Fair enough, but how can I use ||= to avoid this problem?
If the method does return nil, let's just say I want the 'height' to be 0.

I have tried things along the lines of, to no avail:

```
if my_height < self.person_of_age(age)||={ 'height' => 0 }['height']
#...
if my_height < self.person_of_age(age)['height'] ||= 0
```

Clearly my example is running a little thin, and there are other ways around this problem, but if ||= can be used I'd love to know how.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

obvious:

```
(self.person_of_my_age(age) || {'height' => 0})['height']
```

but somehow this does not feel so right

Comment: Or `(self.person_of_my_age(age) || {})['height'] || 0`, or `(self.person_of_mY_age(age) || {}).fetch('height', 0)`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
if my_height < self.person_of_age(age).nil? ? 0 : self.person_of_age(age)['height']
```

Or you can rewrite `person_of_age` method:

```
def person_of_age(age)
  some_hash = @array_of_hashes.select { |h| h.age == age }.last || {:height => 0}
  return some_hash
end
```

or simpler

```
def person_of_age(age)
  @array_of_hashes.select { |h| h.age == age }.last || {:height => 0}      
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps in your circumstance, but one capability Hash has is

```
hash.fetch(key) { block_for_code_evaluated_if_key_absent }
```